# App store reviewing of restricted apps - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, review

I have an application that needs to be activated with a code that sends by SMS, but my SMS provider does not support sending messages to the US, so the application cannot be activated and nobody cannot pass this step. What can I do for this issue?

Comment: maybe you should find a provider who sends text messages to area you'd desire to cover; or just simply stop distributing your app in those territories which are not covered– that is primarily an opinion-based question.

Comment: personal opinion, give the user the option to activate their account with the code that gets sent to them by email as well

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution to your question,

**In your iTune account of this app, select countries only that you want for your app.**

As you said, your SMS provider does not support message for US. It means you have not developed, your app for US country/users. Right?

So select countries only, for whom/those you've created this app (your SMS service provider provides services)

Answer (score 0):

Why not changing your SMS provider first ? I've seen several other one that support sending messages everywhere.